# How do I determine if the mouse button is pressed in java

Tags: java

I've been looking for a while and could only fine semi-useful code and people nothing useful I know I need mouse event but don't know how to declare it.

Comment: In what context? JavaFX, Swing, AWT, Servlet, Applet etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to provide you a very simple and organized sample program that you can build on! Make sure to check out the main Java website if you need help understanding what each method does. Also in the program I have included a very simple main function for a frame, you are welcome to add onto it and test it. I hope this helps! =)

A sample program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Mouse extends Frame implements MouseListener{
    Mouse(){} // Empty constructor.

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // The frame for the program, you can add onto it.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MouseListener");
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Mouse mou = new Mouse();
        frame.addMouseListener(mou);
    }

    // All different events you can use!
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {} 
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {} 
}
```